# How to add other file extensions to SonataMediaBundle?

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata

I need to upload other file types like (.ttf) but i can not.

Now, i'm editing the default source file configuration.php in DependencyInjection. I no it's the worst solution, but i don't know how doing that properly.

in their documentation, they don't suggest any config.

[SonataMediaBundle documentation](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.rst)

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your SonataMediaBundle configuration you have to add `allowed_extensions` and `allowed_mime_types` parameters.

Configuration example for file provider:

```
sonata_media:
    providers:
        file:
            allowed_extensions: ['ttf', 'pdf']
            allowed_mime_types: ['application/octet-stream', 'application/pdf']
```